# PrismaClientValidationerror: Unknown arg column_name in where.column_name

Tags: prisma

How do I resolve resolve PrismaClientValidationError while trying to do an upsert

Model definition

```
model Network {
  id      Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  name    String
  chainId Int     @map("chain_id")

  @@map("networks")
}
```

Upsert

```js
const awaitables = networks.map(async (network) => {
    await prisma.network.upsert({
      where: { name: network.name },
      update: {},
      create: network,
    });
  });
```

I get the following error

```
Unknown arg `name` in where.name for type NetworkWhereUniqueInput. Did you mean `id`? Available args:
type NetworkWhereUniqueInput {
  id?: Int
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to the `NetworkWhereUniqueInput` type not having the name field available as a unique identifier. To resolve this issue, you'll need to update your schema to make the name field unique:

```
model Network {
  id      Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  name    String  @unique
  chainId Int     @map("chain_id")

  @@map("networks")
}
```

By adding the @unique attribute to the name field in your Network model, you're telling Prisma that the name field should be unique, and it can be used in the NetworkWhereUniqueInput type.

You would also need to run `npx prisma generate` to update the Prisma Client with the new schema after making the changes. Now, you should be able to use the name field in your upsert without encountering the error:

```js
const awaitables = networks.map(async (network) => {
  await prisma.network.upsert({
    where: { name: network.name },
    update: {},
    create: network,
  });
});
```

In order for an upsert query to determine whether a record needs to be updated or created it needed to find the record uniquely due to which only fields that are uniquely identifiable needs to be passed in the where clause.

Comment: Thank you. For reference here's the relevant part of the [documentation]( https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#database-upserts)